# Can Flask or Django handle concurrent tasks?

Tags: python, django

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I have a sensor that is constantly reading in data. I need to print this data to a UI whenever data appears. While the aforementioned task is taking place, the user should be able to write data to the sensor. Ideally, both these tasks would / could happen at the same time. Currently, I have the program written using flask; but if django would be better suited (or a third party) I would be willing to make the switch. Note: this website will never be deployed so no need to worry about that. Only user will be me, running program from my laptop.

I have spent a lot of time researching flask async functions and coroutines; however I have not seen any clear indications if something like this would be possible.

Not looking for a line by line solution. Rather, a way (async, threading etc) to set up the code such that the aforementioned tasks are possible. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: flask as all web frameworks can handle concurrent clients at the same time. One can display new data on one page, and other can use different page to write data. Only code which constantly reads data may need to run in separate thread or process - and it can write data to some file or database and web page may read data from file or database when it will need it. And this code you may start even as separated script or separated process in system - it doesn't have to be started by Flask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Django guy, so I'll throw out what I think could be possible

Django has a decorator `@start_new_thread` which can be put on **any** function and it will run in a thread.

- You could make a view, POST to it with Javascript/Ajax and start a thread for communication with the sensor using the data POSTed.
- You could also make a threading function that will read from the sensor

  - Could be a management command or a 'start' btn that POSTs to a view that then starts the thread

**Note:** You need to do `Locks` or some other logic so the two threads don't conflict when reading/writing

- Maybe it's a single thread that reads/writes to the sensor and each loop it checks if there's anything to write (existence + contents of a file? Maybe db entry?

Per the UI, lets say a webpage. You're best best would be Websockets, but because you're the only one that will ever use it you could just write up some Javascript/Ajax that would Ping a view every `x seconds` and display the new data on the webpage

- **Note:** that's essentially what websockets do, ping every x seconds

Now the common thread is Javascript/Ajax, this is so the page doesn't need to refresh and you can constantly see the data coming in without the page being refreshed.

You can probably do all of this in Flask if you find a similar threading ability and just add some javascript to the frontend

Hopefully you find some of this useful, and idk why stackoverflow hates these types of questions... They're literally fine